# Trouble-shooting Google Sheets onEdit script to check cell for value and then run function

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, triggers, google-sheets-api, eventtrigger

I'm trying to write a Google Sheets script that will check for an edit made in a specific cell on one sheet, which will then trigger a function that copies and pastes data from a different sheet into a third sheet. The first sheet, then, is merely used to trigger the actual running of the script, and is where I think the problem lies.

I have tried so many different ways throughout the day to make this work and I just can't get the script to trigger when editing the cell. However, if I manually run the second part (the function) separately - i.e. without the trigger - then that bit works fine, so this leads me to conclude I'm doing something wrong in the trigger section. That said, the execution transcript in the developer console doesn't come up with any errors, so I'm completely bamboozled.

Here's the code:

```
  function DistributeOnEdit(event) {

   var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
   if (sheet.getName() !== "DO NOT DELETE" || event.range.getA1Notation() !== "F10") return;

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var source_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("EDIT: Basic Info");
  var last_source_row = source_sheet.getLastRow();
  var sourceData = source_sheet.getRange("B"+(last_source_row)+":"+"C"+(last_source_row)).getValues();
  var target_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Pay");
  var last_row = target_sheet.getLastRow();
  target_sheet.insertRowAfter(last_row);
  target_sheet.getRange("A"+(last_row+1)+":"+"B"+(last_row+1)).setValues(sourceData);
  }
```

So, I'm trying to check cell **F10** on the tab *DO NOT DELETE* to trigger the script when it changes to *'Yes'*. The second part of the script, I think, is unimportant for this question but for clarity, I want that to take the last row of data in columns **B** and **C** - in the tab *'EDIT: Basic Info'* and paste it into the tab called *'Pay'*.

What am I doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: In order to correctly understand your situation, can I ask you about your question? Your script works fine, when you manually run at the script editor. On the other hand, about ``I just can't get the script to trigger when editing the cell.``, the function of ``DistributeOnEdit()`` is not run (or the script below the if statement is not run.), even if the function is installed as OnEdit trigger. Is my understanding correct? And if you can do, can you provide a sample spreadsheet to replicate your situation? If I'm misunderstanding your question, I apologize.

Comment: Thanks for responding @tanaike - if I understand you correctly, you're asking if I have installed the script as an installable trigger. If so, I have not. Do I need to do that? I thought that was only needed if you wanted, for instance, to run the script on a periodic basis (like every 24 hours, for instance). Am I being stupid? Do you need to install as an installable trigger for this to work? Either way, I have created a very basic version of my spreadsheet if necessary. [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_g7sazCO7cnMSh79nX1PoHQ_NJmyegHO8YrHt6Z69EU/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to run the script when you edit the cells, please install the OnEdit trigger. If you want to run the script with a time (cycle), please install the time driven trigger. You can see the document at [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable). Is this information useful for your situation?

Comment: I've installed the OnEdit trigger, and it works to a degree (I foolishly left out a bit of code where it checks for the 'Yes' string, but have since added that) - however, it only works when I physically change the cell myself. I have a formula to change that cell in the real spreadsheet, and it doesn't work when that formula changes. Should I change this to a OnChange trigger instead? I've had a read about them and can't see if that's the right option.

Comment: I apologize. I couldn't understand your reply.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've since realised the error of my ways anyway. For anyone else reading this and wondering what the issue is - I simplified the initial problem. The cell I wanted to fire the onEdit trigger when it changed to 'Yes' has a formula that does this. Sadly, the limitations of Google Sheets/Javascript is that this must be entered manually, and there's no workaround for this. I have to think of another way to achieve my goals. Thanks @tanaike for all of your help in trying to resolve this.